# Opening new tab in a div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I am creating an app for network design and I need to be able to load a blank div when the user clicks on the New button.
The JQuery UI has a functionality exactly how I want it to be but it uses text area and if I use this, I won't be able to click and drag into the div.
This is the [link](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/#manipulation).
These are my codes found on liveweave: http://liveweave.com/neFP7y and the following is the screenshot:
[image]

I need the tab to open in the blank space. Any idea how I can do this please?

Thanks.

Comment: Reason for downvote? I'm sure it would be helpful to state your reason.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<div> your page 

  <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com//" height="400px;"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Any explanation please?

Comment: The <iframe> tag specifies an inline frame.

An inline frame is used to embed another document within the current HTML document.